# How to confirm plans?

Tags: translation, set-phrases

If you make plans to meat with someone, what's the best way to confirm the plans are still on. Something like "We're still meeting up tonight, right?"

Would anything like the following work, or is there a set phrase for this type of situation?

まだ今晩会いますね。

まだ今晩会いたいでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, まだ doesn't get along with instantaneous verbs like 会う while it does with ones that stand for state like 会いたい, 会うつもりだ or 会える. Something like また(again) is better.

When you confirm something you are not fully sure of, 今晩また会います**よね？** works. If you say …会いますね, you are 100% sure that it's scheduled.

今でも まだ会いたいでしょう**？** works when you point out that the opponent still miss you in reality.